# Editing a comment in app shows incorrect character count

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

Editing a comment always at first shows the "15 chars to go" message for fresh comments - this updates to the correct count on typing the first character.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build.  It was just missing the logic to update the field when editing.